# Best way to stop and repeat coroutine, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, restart, cancellation

I have an android app that draws time consuming graphs when slider moves. If slider moves fast I want to stop current drawing of graph and restart it. Once slider stops I finish the last job.
I am using coroutine for drawing it. What is the best way to stop a coroutine and then start it over?

Comment: just cancel the coroutine job https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin restart operation for coroutines, but you can just `cancel()` already running one and invoke `launch()` (or any other coroutine builder) again to start it from the beginning.

But... for your specific case I suggest reading about [reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) and especially about: [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or [Kotlin flows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html). They were invented specifically to solve these kinds of problems.

See this example using flows:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() {
    // simulate slider position changes
    val sliderFlow = flow {
        emit(1)
        delay(50)
        emit(2)
        delay(50)
        emit(3)
        delay(50)
        emit(4)
        delay(800)
        emit(5)
        delay(1500)
        emit(6)
    }
    sliderFlow.collectLatest { drawGraph(it) }
}

suspend fun drawGraph(input: Int) {
    println("started drawing $input...")
    try {
        delay(1000) // simulate drawing
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        println("cancelled drawing $input")
        throw e
    }
    println("ended drawing $input")
}
```

`sliderFlow` is a stream of slider positions (created for testing purposes). For each new position `drawGraph()` is invoked which takes 1000ms to finish. As we are only interested in the latest position, we use [collectLatest()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect-latest.html) which automatically cancels the processing of a value if a new one arrives. It produces this output:

```
started drawing 1...
cancelled drawing 1
started drawing 2...
cancelled drawing 2
started drawing 3...
cancelled drawing 3
started drawing 4...
cancelled drawing 4
started drawing 5...
ended drawing 5
started drawing 6...
ended drawing 6
```

As we can see, only `5` and `6` has completed, the rest was cancelled, because new slider value was emitted before `drawGraph()` was able to finish.

Additionally, if the slider can move really fast, then we probably don't want to start drawing for each new value, because then we would start drawing only to cancel just milliseconds later. In that case we can use [debounce()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html) which will wait for the value to "stabilize" for specified amount of time:

```kotlin
sliderFlow
    .debounce(100)
    .collectLatest { drawGraph(it) }
```

Output:

```
started drawing 4...
cancelled drawing 4
started drawing 5...
ended drawing 5
started drawing 6...
ended drawing 6
```

As we can see, we didn't even start drawing `1`, `2` and `3`, because they were replaced with new values too quickly.

Comment: `delay` is a suspending function with mutual cancellation baked in - what happens if you are doing blocking computation work in your collector i.e heavy drawing computation rather than your simulated drawing? Wouldn't emissions just be sequential anyway as cancellation has to be mutual (you could probably simnulate that with a Thread.sleep(1000) instead of delay(1000))?  Moreover you'd have to do periodic checks in the draw function i.e. isActive and either return to stop computation or throw an explicit `CancellationException` to free up for the next upstream emission

Comment: Yes, drawing operation has to cooperate in cancelling, e.g. by checking `isActive` from time to time. I didn't mention this, because OP explicitly asked about scheduling of cancellations and restarts of a coroutine and not about how to implement drawing so it responds to cancellations. I got an impression that drawing is already cancellable or that this is not a problem.

Comment: I suppose the ideal situation would be if you are plotting a graph that there is some loop of points doing the bulk of the draw function work that could easily be hooked into to check for cancellation.   Glad we're on the same page for mutual cancellation and upstream emissions as it was a genuine sanity check question!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works with cancelling only already. Just needed to check if isActive at some places. Will also try to use the flow in the future, looks like a good tool for these kinds of things

Comment: cancelAndJoin() before restarting does the job. Just need to have yield() or ensureActive() in my coroutines